# Registered a .PRO domain, can't change DNS for 120 days?

Tags: domains, dns

I noticed the following in [Gandi's terms and conditions for .PRO domains](https://www.gandi.net/static/contracts/en/pro/pdf/special_conditions_PRO_2.1.pdf):

> Once the domain has been registered, you cannot modify the contacts or DNS for 120 days.

What the heck? How am I supposed to point a .PRO domain at my host then?

Comment: Can't you set that when you register it? If not then it is odd that you can't change it right away.

Comment: The controls to change my DNS settings are available, which contradicts the TOS. I've contacted support so I suppose we'll see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gandi's support responded:

> This information is not valid any more, you can modify your contacts and
>   DNS just after the registration of a .PRO domain. The contract will be corrected very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the TOS in question, since I'm unable to find it.

I used Gandi years ago, back then their interface and TOS were a little odd, but I never had any issues with them. Think you did the right thing contacting Gandi's support, but if you have the controls to change the DNS setting within the account as you commented you do, I'd just try change the settings and see if the changes then work; clearly it takes a number of hours, if not days in some cases for that to happen; again, this might create a TOS, but find that hard to believe.

PS-Clearly if this is the case, seems to part with their moto "no bullshit"... :-)

Comment: The TOS is linked in the original question. Search the PDF for the phrase "once the domain."

Comment: +1 @emddudley: Wow, no idea how I missed that, thanks. So, I agree that your reading of the terms appears to be correct. I haven't used Gandi in years, since they raised their prices and the exchange rates changed. Did you have back from Gandi support?